# Convert a JavaScript array of long dates to a string of comma separated short dates using join

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am making an AJAX request to a web service and the service returns a list of DateTimes as JSON.

**In the success function I am doing:**

```
dates = $.parseJSON(data);
var shortDatesString = resetDates.join(", ");
alert(shortDatesString);
```

Any I can use the toLocalDateString() function on these dates while joining them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are valid dates, you can use `map()` to run a method on each dateTime as a date object

```
var dates  = $.parseJSON('[' + data + ']');

var parsed = dates.map(function(date) { 
    var d = new Date(date);
    return d.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric' });
});

var shortDateString = parsed.join(", ");
```

Comment: This works great, but only when I remove the '[' from the parseJSON function like this $.parseJSON(data)... What is the purpose of those? It says invalid date when I use them.

Comment: You're wrapping the returned data in an array, which you likely don't need if you're already returning an array. If you just set `dataType : "json"` in your ajax call, you wouldn't need the `$.parseJSON` at all.

Comment: Yeah I am returning Json from my controller and my AJAX dataType was "html". Thank you!